# How to get system page size in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I have searched in modules `Sys`, `Gc`, and `Unix`, but did not find a means to get the system page size in OCaml. How can we get the system page size?

I have OCaml 4.06 and macOS 10.12.6 (Sierra)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `sysconf(SC_PAGESIZE)` from ocaml to get that information. You can either do that using a `.c` file, or using `ctypes` (although you'll need the value of the `SC_PAGESIZE`, so it might not be the best solution):

```
% utop -require ctypes.foreign
# open Foreign;;
# open Ctypes;;
# let sysconf = foreign "sysconf" (int @-> returning long);;
val sysconf : int -> Signed.long = <fun>
# sysconf 30;;
- : Signed.long = <long 4096>
```

Comment: This worked in macOS but with `sysconf 29`. Did you mistyped the argument, or did it work in a different OS?

Comment: Even though I accepted your answer, I think @PatJ's answer in the comments below is more succint, and provides a useful link to the extensive [Extunix](http://ygrek.org.ua/p/ocaml-extunix/) library.

Comment: That was on linux. As I mentioned, this is not very portable so you're better off using a C stub, which is what extunix must be doing.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want the answer for MacOS, there is a `pagesize` command that you can run with `Unix.open_process_in`:

```
$ rlwrap ocaml
        OCaml version 4.06.0

# #load "unix.cma";;
# Unix.open_process_in "pagesize" |> input_line |> int_of_string;;
- : int = 4096
```

**Update**

There is a POSIX command line program `getconf` that is quite portable, I believe. It works on macOS and all the versions of Linux I tried. You can use that instead:

```
$ rlwrap ocaml
        OCaml version 4.06.0

# #load "unix.cma";;
# Unix.open_process_in "getconf PAGE_SIZE" |> input_line |> int_of_string;;
- : int = 4096
```

Comment: Ok for macOS. What about a general solution for any OS where OCaml runs? I would prefer using some library, like [ocaml-unix-unistd](https://github.com/dsheets/ocaml-unix-unistd), but I do not know how to use this library and no examples are provided in the documentation of the library.

Comment: I looked at the unix-unistd library for a while and could not figure out a way to retrieve the pagesize. From the looks of it the Sysconf submodule just manipulates a small record containing an integer called pagesize. But there's no relation to the actual system pagesize (that I could find). However I believe `getconf` is quite portable. I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield maybe [Extunix](http://ygrek.org.ua/p/ocaml-extunix/) can do the trick though it seems to be system-dependent as well.

Comment: @PatJ This works on macOS: `ExtUnixAll.sysconf PAGESIZE;;` This is the kind of solution I expected to find, and I would pick as the answer if you had responded directly to my question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was looking more for an API, hence I accepted Étienne Millon answer.